# Ignore/disable usercontrol postback if javascript is enabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, postback, client-side

I've searched high and low for some resolution to this problem. Hopefully someone here can explain!!

I create a usercontrol that uses .NET web controls, but I want to create a smoother user experience by avoiding full postbacks, so I write some JQUERY to capture click events on the client and in this way do the processing without going back to the server.

```
        $("#tblLedgerEntries :checkbox").click(function () {
            var value1 = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.invoiceAmount").html();
            var value2 = $('#<%=hdnTotalToPay.ClientID%>').html();
            CalculateTotalPayable(value1, value2, $(this).attr("checked"));
        });
```

All fine. Now someone comes to my site with javascript DISABLED. Let's assume I can detect whether javascript is enabled or otherwise. In this situation I will need to do the calculations I was doing on the client on the server which means I need to trigger a postback....

How do I do this.....I only want to trigger a full postback if javascript is disabled. I want to use the client script if javascript is enabled. If this is applying to checkboxes (UI recalculates a payable amount each time a user clicks a row checkbox), the only way I can see to trigger a postback is by using AutoPostBack=True....but this will always do a postback regardless of the client script.....arghhh.

Anyone know how to do this....or am I approaching this from the wrong angle?!??

Kind Regards

Richard

Answer (score 4):

`AutoPostBack = true` is implemented via javascript.  So if the user has javascript disabled, that won't work either.  The only way to get a PostBack when javascript is disabled is with a usercontrol which gets rendered to the client as an `<input type="submit" />` since that causes the browser to post the form.  Any server controls which render `javascript:__doPostBack()` links will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably can do it using UpdatePanel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386454%28VS.90%29.aspx

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

But of course, the logics will be in the server, using ajax or postbacks, not in the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnSave").attr('disabled', true);
```